# Find nested object in collection

Tags: javascript, hash

Deeply iterate over elements of a collection, returning the first element that the callback returns truey for.

```js
function find(collection, needle) {
  ...
}

var collection = {
  'key1': [
    { 'uuid': '123', 'a': 'a' },
    { 'uuid': '456', 'b': 'b',
      'randomKeyValue': [
        { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
      ]
    }
  ],
  'key2': [
    { 'uuid': '890', 'c': 'c' }
  ]
}

//usage
find(collection, 'uuid') => { 'uuid': '123', 'a': 'a' }

find(collection, '456')  => { 'uuid': '456', 'b': 'b',
  'randomKeyValue': [
    { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
  ]
}

find(collection, { 'uuid': '456' }) => { 'uuid': '456', 'b': 'b',
  'randomKeyValue': [
    { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
  ]
}

find(collection, { 'uuid': '349' }) => { 'uuid': '349', 'd': 'd' }
```

Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your examples don't match your description and signature, because `uuid`, `435` etc are not callbacks. With a callback, a possible implementation could be like this:

```
const nil = {};

function find(obj, pred) {
    if (pred(obj))
        return obj;

    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {

        if (!Array.isArray(obj))
            obj = Object.values(obj);

        for (let x of obj) {
            let t = find(x, pred);
            if (t !== nil)
                return t;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

where `pred` is a function that accepts whatever and returns boolean.

If you also want to use `find` with literal values, like in your examples, you'll need another function that gets a value and returns a predicate that compares an object with that value.

Answer (score 0):

i will try to help with the first two and the final one is almost the same...

```
function find(collection, query /**i think a query not a callback */) {
  if (typeof query === "string")
    for (key in collection)
      return collection[key].find(obj => obj[query] !== undefined || Object.values(obj).indexOf(query) !== -1);
  else if (typeof query === "object") console.log("object");
}
```